# CSS show/hide div on Form Submit Response

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there a way to show (using CSS) specific divs based on the outcome (success, error) of form submission? I am trying to work off an example of achieving this, but having mixed success.

Here is the form setup (I am using Ghost CMS forms, which is the explanation of the floating `data-members-form`):

```html
<form data-members-form>
    <input data-members-label type="hidden" value="Free" />
    <input data-members-email type="email" required="true" placeholder="jenny.doe@example.com"
        class="w-full appearance-none rounded border shadow p-3 text-grey-dark mr-2 focus:outline-none">
    <button
        class="w-full p-2 mt-5 py-5 bg-primary-600 text-white font-medium rounded hover:bg-primary-800 hover:font-semibold">
        <span class="button-content">Sign Up for Free</span>
        <span class="button-loader text-white">{{> "icons/loader"}}</span>
    </button>
    <div class="form-response-messages">
        <div class="form-success bg-green-300 text-green-800 border-green-900 border rounded-lg my-5 p-5">Awww yeah,
            Success! Please check your email to login.</div>
        <div class="form-error bg-red-300 text-red-800 border-red-900 border rounded-lg my-5 p-5">Oh no! Looks like
            there was an error. Please try again.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
form[data-members-form] .form-response-messages {
    display: none;
}

/*-- Show success message on success --*/
form[data-members-form].success .form-response-messages .form-success {
    display: block;
}

/*-- Show error message on error --*/
form[data-members-form].error .form-response-messages .form-error {
    display: block;
}
```

Otherwise, what would be the best method in jQuery to display the elements based on their response?

Answer (score 0):

if you use javascript or jquery just add and remove classes to the divs and have the css for those classes already applied